Dummy data consts fetch dart, flutter
Can someone help me please. I am trying to display the data from Consts.dart file in a widget such as Listview or listview builder. I got errors 'Not String type' etc. I am new to this. I appreciate if anyone help me to make an example here.
I don't want to use classes since I am new. I am drawing UI with a dummy data. Also is this a good way to storage data like this for just UI. Sorry i am learning, checked examples and they were too complicated for me.
 const dummyData = [
  {
    'imagePath': 'assets/images/blue/1.jpg',
    'category': 'cows',
    'author': 'John',
    'animalImage': 'assets/images/1.jpg',
    'date': '21.15.2004',
    'title': 'Lorem ipsum dollar',
    'content':
        'Sed mi ante, hendrerit at suscipit quis, sodales vitae est. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Duis laoreet scelerisque mauris. Cras eleifend mauris orci. Ut ante felis, volutpat non sapien id,',
  },
  {
    'imagePath': 'assets/images/white/image_1.jpg',
    'category': 'dogs',
    'author': 'John',
    'animalImage': 'assets/images/1.jpg',
    'date': '21.15.2004',
    'title': 'Sodales vitae est.',
    'content':
        'Sed mi ante, hendrerit at suscipit quis, sodales vitae est. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Duis laoreet scelerisque mauris. Cras eleifend mauris orci. Ut ante felis, volutpat non sapien id,',
  },
  {
    'imagePath': 'assets/images/green/image_1.jpg',
    'category': 'cats',
    'author': 'John',
    'animalImage': 'assets/images/1.jpg',
    'date': '21.15.2004',
    'title': 'Cats ',
    'content':
        'Sed mi ante, hendrerit at suscipit quis, sodales vitae est. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Duis laoreet scelerisque mauris. Cras eleifend mauris orci. Ut ante felis, volutpat non sapien id,',
  },
];


 return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: dummyData.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Column(
            children: [Image.asset(dummyData), Text(dummyData)],
          );
        },
      ),
    );

A beautiful images of animals and and the content from dummy data to use on the other pages as well

dummyData is a List<Map<String,String>> so you can access it's items in a list view as the following:
ListView.builder(
        itemCount: dummyData.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index) {
          return Column(
            children: [
                 Image.asset(dummyData[index]['imagePath']),
                 Text(dummyData[index]['category'])],
          );
    },
  ),

where dummyData[index] is a MapEntry (item), you need to access it's fields using the key.

Thank you but it says String? can't be assigned to the paramater type 'String' it works after adding '!' is there any solution to solve this in a different way

@melearning, if it's nullable, just decalare dummyData as const List<Map<String,String>> dummyData =....
